# creating a graphNEL object from data

Tags: r, graph

I have a vector of names and a table of distances

Nodes:

```
>V
SERPINA3
ABAT18
ABL1
ACADM
```

Edges:

```
>distances
SERPINA3    1   179 713 627 1937    5984    747 1450    681 718 749 1124    1839    1617    1639    2017    3619    5985    5986                                                   
ABL1    3   175 12  77  81  179 144 174 208 213 223 270 274 282 305 331 348 459 532 517 785 710 889 5988    972 1120    1064    1592    1322    1324    1331    1373    1526    1566    1717    1718    1802    1847    1947
ABAT18  2 5987                                               
ACADM   4   5998
```

From this two files I would like to create a graphNEL object with this command:

```
gR <- new("graphNEL", nodes=V, edgeL=edL1)
```

Does anyone has an idea as to how this should be done. I somehow can't get the list of distances into a list of lists to fit the edgL model.

After running this commad:

```
edL1 <- vector("list", length=ncol(Dist1))
names(edL1) <- V
for(i in 1:ncol(Dist1))
 edL1[[i]] <- list(edges=Dist1[,i], weights=sqrt(i))
gR <- new("graphNEL", nodes=V, edgeL=edL1)
```

I keep getting this error:

> NA element in edges.
>
> The graph is undirected and the following edges are not reciprocated:
>    NA|SERPINA3, NA|ABAT18, NA|ABL1, NA|ACADM
>
> Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “graphNEL” object: FALSE

But there are no NAs in the data.
Does anyone has an Idea?

Thanks
Assa

Comment: every node in list is a list where `$edges` in the list is a vector of indexes of nodes, not names of nodes and `$weight` is a vector of the same length with weights (this one I think you got correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran across a similar error in trying to make a graphNEL object. My problem was that the elements of edges list should be the indices of the nodes - so an example edgeL might look like

```
$SERPINA3
$SERPINA3$edges
[1] 1, 2, 4
```

versus what one might initially expect (the following is *incorrect*):

```
$SERPINA3
$SERPINA3$edges
[1] 'SERPINA3', 'ABL1', 'ACADM'
```

I don't quite understand how the edgeL elements map onto the nodes you created in V (i.e., how do the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 or 179, 175, 5987, 5998 relate to the elements of V?) so I can't provide an answer specific to your data but employing indices as opposed to node names solved my problem.

EDIT:

I've run into the exact problem you describe and found a [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2007-February/015989.html) that gave useful advice. Create an directed graph first and use the ugraph function to retrieve the 'underlying' undirected graph that's represented by your directed graph.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this myself for a while. The [documentation](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/graph/man/graph.pdf) is not very clear. In the end I found the answer in the documentation of the [Rgraphviz package](http://mae.ucdavis.edu/dsouza/Lectures/Rgraphviz.pdf).

You can initialize the graph without assigning the edges:

```
gR = new("graphNEL", nodes = V, edgemode = "directed")
```

Then you can add edges one by one using:

```
gR = addEdge("SERPINA3", "ABAT18", gR, 5987)
```

I'm sure this is not *the* way to go, but my graphs have few edges so I stopped searching for a better alternative.

Comment: This works, but it is very very slow solution. If you actually define a list of edges in advance it is way way faster...

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a matrix that captures all edges. 
As an example:

```
From <- c("A","A","C","C")

To <- c("B","C","B","D")

L <- cbind(From,To)

mygraphNEL <- ftM2adjM(L, edgemode="directed")
```

More details [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~richard/courses/bioconductor2007/CDrom/Graphs/graphBasics.pdf).